Stroke overlap in Border element using MAUI XAML
I am trying to make a card like this using XAML in MAUI:
XAML MAUI Card on Android
I am having problems with content overlapping the actual Border (Stroke) on Android Emulator.
When I run it on Windows, it's vice versa - the content gets overlapped by Border (Stroke) like this:
XAML MAUI Card on Windows
Here's the code for the card.
        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="30">
            <Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20" StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="Black">
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <Label Padding="0,0,0,20" TextColor="Red" Text="Header" BackgroundColor="yellow"/>
                    <Label Text="Content" />
                    <Label Text="Content" />
                    <Label Text="Content" />
                    <Label Text="Content" />
                    <Label TextColor="Red" Text="Content" />
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </Border>
        </VerticalStackLayout>

To fix this on Windows I can just add padding to first and last elements, but then to line them all up I have to add padding to ALL of them (or at wrap the ones without BackgroundColor with another element and add padding to that element like this) and I end up with quite a mess of elements and paddings like this.
<VerticalStackLayout Padding="30">
    <Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20" StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="Black">
        <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label Padding="5,0,0,20" TextColor="Red" Text="Header" BackgroundColor="yellow"/>
                <VerticalStackLayout Padding="5,0,0,0">
                    <Label Text="Content" />
                    <Label Text="Content" />
                    <Label Text="Content" />
                    <Label Text="Content" />
                    <Label TextColor="Red" Text="Content" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Border>
</VerticalStackLayout>

While I can fix the problem on Windows, I can't think of a way of how to fix it on Android.
Why is this happening and how do I fix this problem?

What‘s the system version of the Android emulator you are using?

You can try adding Padding to the  inside the .

@ShuowenHe-MSFT Pixel 5 - API 34 (Android 14.0 - API 34)

@ShuowenHe-MSFT If I add padding to the VerticalStackLayout, I get a white gap around my header part

I reproduced your problem. On android platform, if set the background color to the label, it will cover the thick border. You can post this issue to github.

Create filler with two dummy Rectangles. One top, one bottom.

You may try adding an additional Border element with the same StrokeShape inside the outer Border. Try the following code,
<Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20" StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="Black">
    <Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20" StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="Black">
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Label Padding="5,0,0,20" TextColor="Red" Text="Header" BackgroundColor="yello
            <VerticalStackLayout Padding="5,0,0,0">
                <Label Text="Content" />
               ......
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Border>
</Border>

Then the background color will not overlap the Border stroke.
